# Aframe vue video change src

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to create a video dashboard, with a list of videos.

I'm currently using `:src` to change the  `src` on a `<a-video>` component.
While video changes on user input (keyboard input for now), the old one seems to be playing in the background even after the `src` is changed.

My guess its that since aframe and vue all create their own virtual dom, even if vue destroyed the item on `src` change, aframe still caches it thus playing back regardless of the state in vue.

Is there any way I can re-initiate the `<a-video>` with every data changes on vue side?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `:src` when using a `<a-video>` tag alone will really not work.

**Suggested workaround:** use `<a-asset>` to keep the video and then change its source.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    srcJungle: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4',
    srcCity: 'https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/',
    currentSrc: ''
  },
  created() {
    this.currentSrc = this.srcJungle;
  } 
})
```

```css
a-scene canvas {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>Current src: {{ currentSrc }}</pre>
  
  <button @click="currentSrc = srcCity" :disabled="currentSrc === srcCity">
  Change to City (takes some time to load)</button>
  <button @click="currentSrc = srcJungle" :disabled="currentSrc === srcJungle">
  Change to Jungle (takes some time to load)</button>
  <hr>
  <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
      <video id="vue-video" autoplay loop="true" :src="currentSrc"></video>
    </a-assets>
    <a-video src="#vue-video" width="100%" height="100%"  position="0 0 -20">
  </a-video>
</a-scene>
</div>
```

Note: using `<a-video>` only does not work. Seems like a bug.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    srcJungle: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4',
    srcCity: 'https://ucarecdn.com/fadab25d-0b3a-45f7-8ef5-85318e92a261/',
    currentSrc: ''
  },
  created() {
    this.currentSrc = this.srcJungle;
  } 
})
```

```css
a-scene canvas {
   border: 1px solid red;
   height: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <pre>Current src: {{ currentSrc }}</pre>
  
  <button @click="currentSrc = srcCity" :disabled="currentSrc === srcCity">
  Change to City (takes some time to load)</button>
  <button @click="currentSrc = srcJungle" :disabled="currentSrc === srcJungle">
  Change to Jungle (takes some time to load)</button>
  <hr>
  <a-scene :key="currentSrc">
    <a-video :src="currentSrc" width="100%" height="100%"  position="0 0 -20">
  </a-video>
</a-scene>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems that if I put video in assets and load them via compute tag, it's working fine. I was using a single <a-video> tag which seems to work differently then a linking assets to the tag itself.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Seems like a bug. I'd open a ticket in their issue tracker ( https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues ). Meanwhile the `<a-assets>` is a valid workaround.